# Python: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 2 element

Tags: python, excel, finance, yahoo

I am very very new to Python (no coding history or skills whatsoever). I have been trying to automate pulling data from Yahoo and have built the following program from whatever I could find on the net. SO please excuse the poor coding attempt (however it almost works perfectly for me).

- I am trying to download listed financial stock data (as you'll see in the code)
- I want it downloaded to a specific excel sheet - in its raw form (as I link it to another excel sheet which runs my calculations).

Here is the problem. The following code works perfectly for all US stocks, a bunch of EU stocks but none for Australian / NZ and some EU stocks where i get the error: "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 2 element"

I am absolutely stumped. It was working previously - then I started playing around with matplotlib and now nothing is working for Australian / New Zealand (and some EU) Stocks.

Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated and again, I am brand new to this so please go easy: Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf 
import yahoofinancials
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import *
from openpyxl import load_workbook 



x = input("Enter Stock: ")
a = (x)

datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter("File.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')

data = stats_df = si.get_stats(a)
stats_df.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Stats')

data = StatsVal_df = get_stats_valuation(x)
StatsVal_df.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Stats Val')

data = BS_df = si.get_balance_sheet(a)
BS_df.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Balance Sheet')

data = IS_df = si.get_income_statement(a)
IS_df.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='PnL')

data = CF_df = si.get_cash_flow(a)
CF_df.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='CashFlow')

Data = Data_df = get_data(x)
Data_df.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Historical Price History')

datatoexcel.save()
```

The issue is mainly contained to:

```
data = stats_df = si.get_stats(a)
stats_df.to_excel(datatoexcel, sheet_name='Stats')
```

so, for example, I will run "GOOGL" / "AAPL" / "MSFT" / "BSX" / "BMW.DE" and it works perfectly. Yet, when I run "NAN.AX" / "CBA.AX" or any other stock like that - i get the error: *Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 2 element*

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for yahoo_fin, it mentions that data is retrieved by scraping the yahoo page for the selected stock. Without a paid Yahoo account, you can't see data for foreign stocks.

US stock: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NFLX/key-statistics?p=NFLX

Foreign: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CBA.AX/key-statistics?p=CBA.AX

The documentation can be found here:

http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/#get_stats

To clarify the issue, you can run this code:

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
print('AAPL', len(si.get_stats('AAPL')))
print('CBA.AX', len(si.get_stats('CBA.AX')))
```

Output

```
AAPL 50
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

Comment: thanks for the info Mike, the weird thing is, I was accessing the premium info without the need for a login - then tried to amend the code to include a graph (matplot etc) and immediately thereafter - couldn't access certain stocks based on that lenght mismatch error message above.

Comment: I added a code snippet in the answer. You can run it in the python terminal to narrow down the issue. Concerning the premium account, I can only assume you used a different stock symbol previously or you had temporary access to premium data.

Comment: thanks again Mike - appreciate it. Strangely I have none of the premium access or different stock codes? that is what I am finding so confusing! Appreciate all your efforts. I am actually only chasing a few key pieces of information so may need to manually input those....sadly (or go down learning how to use API keys etc). All the best.